# Am I understanding semantic entailment correctly?

Tags: semantics, entailment

I'm trying to make sure I understand entailment properly, but my prof basically said two sentences that only briefly explained what entailment is, and he's not teaching this course with a textbook.

In this example:

(a) The dog was fed

(b) Johnny fed the dog a treat

Does sentence (a) entail sentence (b), or is it mutual entailment? I don't think it's mutual because the dog being fed doesn't necessarily mean that Johnny was the one who fed it. A similar example was this:

(a) The children were served candy for dinner

(b) The children ate candy

Am I overthinking it to wonder if the children being served candy doesn't necessarily mean they ate candy?

Finally:

(a) John and Susie love each other

(b) John loves Susie

I think sentence (a) entails sentence (b), but I wonder if they contradict each other.

Comment: Your answer is fine.

Comment: You are right about everything, about the third question, John can love Suisse independent of Suisse loving him